# How to decrease space between footnote mark and next text?

Tags: footnotes

In Russian typesetting the footnote is usually placed between text & closing punctuation character, like:

```
this is example\footnote{footnote example}.
```

But this leads to empty space between the footnote marker and the punctuation character, as you can see on the image:

[image: Example of space between footnote mark & punctuation]

Is it possible to decrease this space? I've tried following redefinition, but it didn't help:

```
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\origfootnote{#1}\hspace{-0.6em}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
русский текст\footnote{тест}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `fnpct` package using it with `\setfnpct{punct-after=true}`

Comment: Can you present a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the package `fnpct` here which is doing this fix for you. Just make sure to set the punctuation sign *after* the footnote.

The option `punct-after=true` is changing the default to your Russian requirement. I did not check this behaviour with cyrillics as you have not provided an MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[punct-after=true]{fnpct}

\begin{document}
First example\footnote{first example footnote}.

Second example\footnote{second example footnote}:
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**:

As mentioned by cgnieder (the author of that package) in comment you may introduce this option anywhere in your document by the local switch `\setfnpct{punct-after=true}`. As said before, the default in `fnpct` is `false`.

**Edit 2**:

The colon is not having any kerning in `fnpct` which does not disturb in my example. But if the distance is getting as big as in your posted image, you will have to add it to the punctuation marks treated by `fnpct`. This should be done like: `\setfnpct{add-punct-marks={:}[0em][-.08em]}` You may vary that kerning to your needs.

Comment: Per default `fnpct` does not change kerning between footnote marks and colons. They need to be added first, something like `\setfnpct{add-punct-marks={:}[0em][-.08em]}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Nevermind. English isn't my native language either. Errors are bound to happen :)